# Could not create Relay Container; graphql.js file appears to have webpack artifacts?

Tags: webpack, electron, graphql, relay

I'm using Relay with CRA in an Electron container, and I'm getting a very odd error I can't seem to diagnose: it appears the GraphQL fragment, as imported, contains Webpack artifacts?

```
Could not create Relay Container for `UsersGrid`. Expected a set of GraphQL fragments, got `function () {
  const node = __webpack_require__(/*! ./__generated__/UsersGrid_viewer.graphql */ "./src/components/users-grid/__generated__/UsersGrid_viewer.graphql.js");
```

Is Webpack compiling the `.graphql.js` file somehow?  Or is there something else I should be looking at?

This is the Relay container:

```
import { createFragmentContainer, graphql } from 'react-relay';
import UsersGrid from './UsersGrid';

export default createFragmentContainer(
  UsersGrid,
  graphql`
    fragment UsersGrid_viewer on Query {
      user(login: "jvcjunior") {
        followers(first: 10) {
          edges {
            node {
              name
              avatarUrl
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `
);
```

which is getting compiled inline into:

```
/***/ "./src/components/users-grid/UsersGrid.relay.js":
/*!******************************************************!*\
  !*** ./src/components/users-grid/UsersGrid.relay.js ***!
  \******************************************************/
/*! exports provided: default */
/***/ (function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony import */ var react_relay__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! react-relay */ "./node_modules/react-relay/index.js");
/* harmony import */ var react_relay__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(react_relay__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__);
/* harmony import */ var _UsersGrid__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./UsersGrid */ "./src/components/users-grid/UsersGrid.js");


/* harmony default export */ __webpack_exports__["default"] = (Object(react_relay__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["createFragmentContainer"])(_UsersGrid__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["default"], function () {
  const node = __webpack_require__(/*! ./__generated__/UsersGrid_viewer.graphql */ "./src/components/users-grid/__generated__/UsersGrid_viewer.graphql.js");

  if (node.hash && node.hash !== "d730274a63d8021d6427a27e7c3e2c27") {
    console.error("The definition of 'UsersGrid_viewer' appears to have changed. Run `relay-compiler` to update the generated files to receive the expected data.");
  }

  return __webpack_require__(/*! ./__generated__/UsersGrid_viewer.graphql */ "./src/components/users-grid/__generated__/UsersGrid_viewer.graphql.js");
}));

/***/ }),
```

Comment: Hi. I have same problem in react-native with relay@4

Comment: @Alexes Did either of you solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Try using

```
createFragmentContainer(Component, {
  viewer: graphql`
    fragment UsersGrid_viewer on Query { ... }
  `
})
```

instead

```
createFragmentContainer(Component,
  graphql`
    fragment UsersGrid_viewer on Query { ... }
  `
)
```

Comment: Relay wants `typeof fragmentSpec === 'object'` https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/27b3433934dcec084e0b8ec77ede89e86d009031/packages/react-relay/assertFragmentMap.js

Comment: That helps, but I can't understand, why in the docs [the method](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/en/fragment-container.html#createfragmentcontainer) takes mapping `{[string]: GraphQLTaggedNode}` , but in the tutorial they just pass ``graphql` fragment … ` `` string. May be the reason is that babel-plugin-relay must transform one into the other?

Comment: I just upgraded from ^3.0.0 to ^4.0.0 and had to change my containers to pass object instead of graphql`fragment ...`

Comment: Fragment Container, Refetch Container, Pagination Container now always expect an object as the fragment declaration (single graphql tag is no longer valid input), since graphql tags no longer implicitly produce object wrappers during our babel transform

Comment: @Alexes thanks. I made a PR month ago to keep the tutorial up-to-date.